# Nonexistence of the lcm(p, px)

Tags: ring-theory

Let $p \in \mathbb{ Z }$ be a prime number. Define $R \subseteq \mathbb{ Z }[X]$ to be the integral domain such that for any element the coefficient of $x$ is divisible by $p$.

I'm supposed to show that $\mbox{lcm}(p, px)$ does not exist. However, $p^2 x$ is
a multiple of $p$ and $px$. So I guess this must mean that there is some infinite series of decreasing multiples of both $p$ and $px$. Here, though, I am lost. I'm not really sure where to start.

I was wondering if I could get a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your conclusion is correct that you have to be able to find an infinite decreasing series of common multiples of $p$ and $px$. You're forgetting an important property of least common multiples!

**Hint:** If $Q(x)$ is a least common multiple of $p$ and $px$, then *by definition* it would have the property that for any common multiple $S(x)$ of $p$ and $px$, necessarily $Q\mid S$ within the ring $R$. Can you think of an element of $R$ that is a multiple of by $p$ and $px$, but is not divisible by $p^2x$?

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for your help.